# Google Apps Script automatic specific text highlighter

Tags: google-apps-script, highlight

Need an add on / google script where I can enter range of specific text and have it automatically highlighted throughout google docs. I need to use it to automatically highlight keywords in articles/website copy.

Looked at add on scripts - highlighter add on but it only highlights text that user selects and does not repeat the highlight for all same text throughout content. I looked in Google Scripts but I don't know how to define the question or how to create my own code.

Comment: Try a feature request.  Your can find the links you need [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: It would be possible to do in Google Sheets using richTextValues.  You could use createTextfinder for your range and then loop through all of the results creating richTextValues to highlight the appropriate words.

Answer (score 0):

Text Highlighter:

```
function boldMyWords() {
  const red = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setForegroundColor('red').setBold(true).build();
  const bold = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setBold(true).build();
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const dsr = 3;
  const rg = sh.getRange(3, 1, sh.getLastRow() - dsr + 1, sh.getLastColumn());
  rg.clearFormat().setWrap(true);
  let vs = rg.getDisplayValues();
  let r = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt('Enter words to search for separated by commas', SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  if (r.getSelectedButton() == SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.OK) {
    let wordA = r.getResponseText().split(',');
    vs.forEach((r, i) => {
      r.forEach((c, j) => {
        let idxObj = { pA: [] };
        wordA.forEach(w => {
          let re = new RegExp('(\\W|^)' + w.trim().toLowerCase() + '(\\W|$)', 'g');
          let found = [...c.toLowerCase().matchAll(re)];
          found.forEach(f => {
            if (!idxObj.hasOwnProperty(w)) {
              idxObj[w] = [];
              idxObj[w].push((f.index > 0) ? f.index + 1 : f.index);
              idxObj.pA.push(w);
            } else {
              idxObj[w].push((f.index));
            }
          })
        });
        if (idxObj.pA.length > 0) {
          let cell = sh.getRange(i + dsr, j + 1);
          let val = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(c);
          idxObj.pA.forEach((p, k) => {
            idxObj[p].forEach(idx => {
              val.setTextStyle(idx, idx + p.length, red);
              val.setTextStyle(idx, idx + p.length, bold);
            });
          });
          cell.setRichTextValue(val.build());
        }
      });
    });
  }
  ss.toast('EOF')
}
```